# Remove pattern from a column if it is present in another one

Tags: awk, sed

I have this file :

```
>AX-89916436-Affx-G-[A/G]
TTGTCCGAGAGTGACGTCAATCCGCA
>AX-89916437-Affx-A-[A/G]
TGTGTGGAAACTCCG
>AX-89916438-Affx-C-[A/C]
GAAGTACGGTAACAT
>AX-89916440-Affx-T-[G/T]
AGTTGATGGTGTATGTGTGTCTTT
```

I would like to remove in the last field `[X/X]` the letter present in the 4th field. To get something like that :

```
>AX-89916436-Affx-G-A
TTGTCCGAGAGTGACGTCAATCCGCA
>AX-89916437-Affx-A-G
TGTGTGGAAACTCCG
>AX-89916438-Affx-C-A
GAAGTACGGTAACAT
>AX-89916440-Affx-T-G
AGTTGATGGTGTATGTGTGTCTTT
```

I have :

```
 awk -F'-' '
    match($0, /\[[A-Z]\/[A-Z]]/) {m = substr($0, RSTART, RLENGTH); if(/^>/ && $NF~/m/); print ... }'
```

Comment: What should be output for `>AX-89916440-Affx-T-[A/C]` ?

Comment: Nothing. There is necessarily the single letter (T here) in the pattern [X/X]

Comment: You're right, I edited my post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="-"} />/{gsub("[][/]",""); sub($(NF-1),"",$NF)}1' file
>AX-89916436-Affx-G-A
XXXXXXX
>AX-89916437-Affx-A-G
XXXXXXXXXXX
>AX-89916438-Affx-C-A
XXXXXXX
>AX-89916440-Affx-T-G
XXXXXXX
```

Comment: perhaps the gsub should also be for `$NF` in case other fields can have `[]/` characters..

Comment: @Sundeep I THINK we can assume the lines that have those chars don't have them in any other locations or the OP would show them in their example. We're all guessing at what those `XXXXXXX` lines might contain (could they contain `>` or `[...]`?) so I've asked the OP to update their question.

Answer (score 3):

Here is another `awk`:

```sh
awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS="-"} NF>1 {gsub("[][/" $(NF-1) "]", "", $NF) } 1' file

>AX-89916436-Affx-G-A
XXXXXXX
>AX-89916437-Affx-A-G
XXXXXXXXXXX
>AX-89916438-Affx-C-A
XXXXXXX
>AX-89916440-Affx-T-G
XXXXXXX
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```sh
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="-"} /^>/ && $5 ~ /\[[A-Z]\/[A-Z]]/{gsub("[][/"$4"]", "", $5);}1' file
```

*Details*:

- `BEGIN{FS=OFS="-"}` - set input/output field separator to `-`
- `/^>/ && $5 ~ /\[[A-Z]\/[A-Z]]/` - if the string starts with `>` and Field 5 contains `[` + uppercase letter + / + uppercase letter + `]` substring...
- `{gsub("[][/"$4"]", "", $5);}` - then remove from Field 5 `]`, `[`, `/` and Field 4 chars
- `1` - fires the default `print` action.

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/TGenCZ):

```sh
#!/bin/bash
s='>AX-89916436-Affx-G-[A/G]
XXXXXXX
>AX-89916437-Affx-A-[A/G]
XXXXXXXXXXX
>AX-89916438-Affx-C-[A/C]
XXXXXXX
>AX-89916440-Affx-T-[G/T]
XXXXXXX'

awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="-"} /^>/ && $5 ~ /\[[A-Z]\/[A-Z]]/{gsub("[][/"$4"]", "", $5);}1' <<< "$s"
```

Output:

```
>AX-89916436-Affx-G-A
XXXXXXX
>AX-89916437-Affx-A-G
XXXXXXXXXXX
>AX-89916438-Affx-C-A
XXXXXXX
>AX-89916440-Affx-T-G
XXXXXXX
```

Answer (score 2):

With your shown samples, please try following `awk` code. Simple explanation would be setting `FS` and `OFS` as `=` and in main section checking if a line starts from `>` and 5th field is matching regex `\[[A-Z]\/[A-Z]]` then remove whatever values present of 4th field in 5th field using `gsub`. `1` is `awk`sh way of printing current edited/non-edited line.

```
awk '
BEGIN{ FS=OFS="-" }
/^>/ && $5 ~ /\[[A-Z]\/[A-Z]]/{
  gsub("[][/"$4"]", "", $5)
}
1' Input_file
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed -E s'#([A-Z])-\[(\1|([A-Z]))/(\1|([A-Z]))]#\1-\3\5#' input_file
>AX-89916436-Affx-G-A
TTGTCCGAGAGTGACGTCAATCCGCA
>AX-89916437-Affx-A-G
TGTGTGGAAACTCCG
>AX-89916438-Affx-C-A
GAAGTACGGTAACAT
>AX-89916440-Affx-T-G
AGTTGATGGTGTATGTGTGTCTTT
```

Answer (score 0):

much better now :

```
>AX-89916436-Affx-G-A
TTGTCCGAGAGTGACGTCAATCCGCA
>AX-89916437-Affx-A-G
TGTGTGGAAACTCCG
>AX-89916438-Affx-C-A
GAAGTACGGTAACAT
>AX-89916440-Affx-T-G
AGTTGATGGTGTATGTGTGTCTTT

# gawk profile, created Thu May 12 05:05:48 2022

# Rule(s)

8 NF*=($_=(NF=NF)==!_?$!_:$!(NF-=($(_+=(_-=_)-+-++_-+-++_)=\
       $((_+=_+=(_^=_<_)+_)-($--_!=$--_) ) )^(_-=_)+!_))~""'
```